# How to execute a redis extension command with reactiveredisoperations in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-webflux, redisearch

I'm trying to use redisearch with java/spring reactive api. So with nodejs redis client I could just use send_command function and pass any redis command I wanted as an array of strings. This was perfect for sending redisearch commands to redis.

Now I'm using java and Spring Data Reactive Redis. ReactiveRedisOperations interface has an exec method, but it seems that it executes only lua scripts and what-a-not.

Any way of passing redisearch commands to redis server with ReactiveRedisOperations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crafting command requests and parsing responses are not trivial tasks and you might want to use a RediSearch client for Java: https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Clients.html